# how do i split the url using split method by checking all the image extension

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, eclipse

code:

var imgurl : String = http://sits/productimages/00670535922278.png?sw=350&sh=350;
var imagesplit = imgurl.split('.(jpeg|png|jpg|gif)$/');
 i am trying this code but it is not spliting into arrays.
i need to split like

expected output:

imgurl

[0] :http://sits/productimages/00670535922278.png?sw=350&sh=350;

can anyone help me regaurding this

Comment: Did you try splitting using ? sign i.e.  imagesplit = imgurl.split('?'); It will give list of images and then you can easily remove extension.

Comment: i want to split using .png beacuse i need to concat the product name with '_pf' and again need to join complete url       by using split('.png') it will work fine but url is coming dynamically i need check extension and split it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try to do it like this;

```
var imgUrl = "http://sits/productimages/00670535922278.png?sw=350&sh=350;";

var splitterArray = ['.jpeg', '.png', '.jpg', '.gif'];

for (var i = 0; i < splitterArray.length; i++) {
  var imgUrlArray = imgUrl.split(splitterArray[i]);

  if (imgUrlArray.length > 1) {
    //Do your thing here
  }
}
```

You use a array of your extensions that will be checked, and i your string contains the extension your imgUrlArray will have a length grater than one.

Comment: one more way we can achive this..... by using var imagematch : String= imgurl.match('.jpeg|.png|.jpg|.gif');
        var imagesplit: String= imgurl.split(imagematch);